# How to set readonly property of a textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a textbox whose property i need to set as readonly...
how to set that?
I tried

```
document.getElementbyid("txtbox").readonly=true;
document.getElementbyid("txtbox").disable=true;
document.getElementbyid("txtbox").setattribute("readonly","readonly");
```

all these are not working for me.
Disable is working but that is passing the control values as null to the database...again that is a problem for me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set an ASP.NET textbox readonly through javascript.
Here is how:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setReadOnly(){
        var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
        textbox.readOnly = "readonly";//readOnly is cese-sensitive
        }

<body onload=" setReadOnly ()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: This code looks banjaxed anyway. There is no TextBox2 in your sample, and with Asp.Net in order to access the TextBox in javascript you'd need to use the ClientID unless you specifically forced the ID with attributes.

Answer (score 6):

You have numerous issues with the code in your question. The very first example would work if you had got the names of the properties right:

```
document.getElementById("txtbox").readOnly = true;
```

Notice the uppercase letters (`getElementById` instead of `getElementbyid` and `readOnly` instead of `readonly`).

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmfva/) of the above.

As for your 2nd attempt, the property is `disabled`, not `disable`. And your 3rd attempt, the method is `setAttribute`, not `setattribute`. As you can see, JavaScript is case sensitive!

Comment: yup, `.readOnly = true` is really the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way is:

```
document.getElementById("txtbox").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
```

Or for the jQuery enthusiasts:

```
$("#txtbox").attr("readonly", true);
```

Comment: `readonly` is a boolean attribute. The only valid value it can have is "readonly". It is also valid for it not to have a value at all e.g. `<input id="txtbox" readonly>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loading() {

    var input_text = document.getElementById("text");
    input_text.setAttribute("readOnly", true);
    }
```

Works for me well....... use camelcase with property....... readOnly not as readonly.....